# how do i remove a project from a group in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

how do i remove a project from a project group in Netbeans?

I see an option for 'New Group', but there is nothing about adding or removing projects to a group. Also there is a 'Properties of Group' option which has nothing useful in it. This is weird.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the standard settings, all opened projects (at the time of creating the group) have been added to your group. It's also standard that Netbeans remembers which projects have been opened (thus added) or closed (thus removed) while having the group opened.

I think it's quite straight forward but I guess you have expected something else (if this is the case: what have you expected?)

Comment: a group is like a folder. I can add things to it or remove things.

Comment: ah i think i get it now

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. Right click on the project you want to remove
2. Press **"Close"**.

[image: Close the project image]